# Python dataframe detect language and translate

Tags: python, translate

I am trying to detect the language of the dataframe and translate it into English. Apparently the language here is Chinese. How do I translate the column names and the cells in the columns? Any support is appreciated!!!

```
    序号  企业数据    数据维度    接口id    详细URL   计费规则    每次单价

0   1   搜索接口    搜索接口    816 http://open.tianyancha.com/open/816 按次查得计费  0.01

1   2   企业基本信息  企业简介    755 http://open.tianyancha.com/open/755 按次查得计费  0.10

2   3   NaN 企业基本信息  818 http://open.tianyancha.com/open/818 按次查得计费  0.15

3   4   NaN 主要人员    820 http://open.tianyancha.com/open/820 按次查得计费  0.15

4   5   NaN 股东信息    821 http://open.tianyancha.com/open/821 按次查得计费  0.15
```

Comment: So maybe you need to scrapy some website to do that.

Answer (score 0):

To detect the language you could use something like https://pypi.org/project/langdetect/
Then, you could translate the values with https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/